# What should I put in 'require_once' command in PHP if the required file is hosted on the internet?

Tags: php

I hope you are well.

I've hosted two PHP files on my website's File Manager (in cPanel) - which are `sample.php` & `request.php`, as you can see the snap below :

[image: cPanel snap]

The `sample.php` file's code requires the `request.php` file - below's a snippet of the code :

[image: sample.php code snippet]

We actually took both the files from a website as a template and just want to know what to place in the `require_once` area: should we place the **direct URL of the required file** (*ex. mywebsite.com/request.php*) or any other path?

I hope you understand my Query.
Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: The [`include` manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (which also 99% applies to `require` and its other variants) should answer your question. In your case, the safest option would be to use `require __DIR__ . '/request.php';` since it's in the same folder.

Comment: Thanks, @Jeto! Your reply is appreciated. Just to confirm, is this what I should do? - `require_once __DIR__ . '/request.php'` Thanks! 

Comment: Right. That will look for the included file in the current folder (`__DIR__`), aka the folder where the current PHP file resides.